# React.Component vs React.createClass

Tags: reactjs

I am confused whats the difference between a component and a react class?

And when do I use a component over a react class?
Looks like a component is a class and createClass creates a component.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html

**React.Component**

> This is the base class for React Components when they're defined using
>   ES6 classes. See Reusable Components for how to use ES6 classes with
>   React. For what methods are actually provided by the base class, see
>   the Component API.

**React.createClass**

> Create a component class, given a specification. A component
>   implements a render method which returns one single child. That child
>   may have an arbitrarily deep child structure. One thing that makes
>   components different than standard prototypal classes is that you
>   don't need to call new on them. They are convenience wrappers that
>   construct backing instances (via new) for you.

Comment: Be aware that using one syntax or the other contains some caveats. For instance mixins are not supported in the case of `MyComponent extends React.Component`.

Comment: I see this in some reflux examples, where some files are written with component and some with createClass. I read your hint before, but that's lead me to that question. So basically if i want to use mixins, I use createClass. If not I can go with ES6, right ?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The only `React.createClass` functionality that isn't supported by `MyComponent extends React.Component` is mixins.

to do `getInitialState()` you can do:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    // initial state
    this.state = {
      counter: 0
    };
  }

  ...
}
```

or if you use a transpiler like babel, you can get

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0
  }

  ...
}
```

Instead of auto-binding provided by createClass, you could explicitly bind using `.bind(this)` like you have shown above, or use the fat arrow ES6 syntax:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  onClick = () => {
    // do something
  }
  ...
}
```

Instead of putting things in componentWillMount, you could put things in constructor like so:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    // what you would have put in componentWillMount
  }

  ...
}
```

There are way more details in the React documentation themselves, but basically the only additional functionality that React.createClass buys is mixins, but afaik anything you could have done with mixins can be done with context and higher ordered components.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. Thank you for the detailed and up to date explanation.

Answer (score 16):

There are 2 ways of doing the same thing.

`React.createClass` is a function that returns a Component class.

```
MyComponent = React.createClass({
  ...
});
```

`React.Component` is an existing component that you can extend. Mainly useful when using ES6.

```
MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
}
```

Comment: There are more differences. getInitialState() for instance doesn't exist in the ES6 React.Component.

Comment: Look at `Lewis C`'s answer below. It explains the differences.

Answer (score 10):

`React.createClass` - method to create component classes

For better use with ES6 modules by extends `React.Component`, which extends the Component class instead of calling `createClass`

Few differences between both are,

**Syntax :**
React.createClass:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({ });
```

React.Component:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component{ }
```

**getInitialState() :**
React.createClass: 
    Yes
React.Component: 
    No

**constructor() :**
React.createClass: 
    No
React.Component: 
    Yes

**propTypes  Syntax :**
React.createClass:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    propTypes: { }
});
```

React.Component:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component{ }
MyComponent.prototypes = { }
```

**Default Properties :** 
React.createClass:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps(): { return {} }
});
```

React.Component:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component{ }
MyComponent.defaultProps = { }
```

**state :** 
React.createClass:

```
State changes can be made inside getInitialState() function
```

React.Component:

```
State changes can be made inside constructor(props) function
```

**this :**
React.createClass:

```
automatically bind 'this' values.
Ex: <div onClick={this.handleClick}></div>
'this' can be accessed by default in handleClick function
```

React.Component:

```
whereas here we need to bind explicitly,
Ex: <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the examples :) In React.Component: Similar to MyComponent.defaultProps do we have option MyComponent.defaultState ??

Answer (score 3):

It's look like React recommend us to use `React.createClass`

As far as I know

1. `MyComponent extends React.Component` not supported `getInitialState()`
2. Use `.bind(this)` in `React.createClass` you'll get this

   > Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call.

I think it's might be more than this.

If someone list all of `React.createClass` functionality will be so great.

Note: React is currently in 0.14.3

Comment: According to this https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/10/react-v0.13.html from v0.13, they plan to remove at some point the React.createClass() syntax in favor from the other one

`Our eventual goal is for ES6 classes to replace React.createClass completely, but until we have a replacement for current mixin use cases and support for class property initializers in the language, we don't plan to deprecate React.createClass.`

Answer (score 0):

To be honest the only difference is that React.createClass uses mixins and the new ES6 syntax doesn't.

Both are just syntax, choose what works best for you. React actually wants to deprecate React.createClass in favour of ES6 syntax in future updates.

So I recommend you and future users to check these links, as most of the answer on this thread are related and explained in details.

https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/react-create-class-versus-component

https://www.newline.co/fullstack-react/articles/react-create-class-vs-es6-class-components/

Comment: Ohh I see, I just thought it would be unnecessary repetition since the code examples and snippet are already on that page from the link.

But thanks for the tip, I would implement this moving on!