# What's the difference between `React.createElement(...)` and `new MyComponent()`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Intro:** I'm a bit confused with React. I've seen articles saying that React components are just functions that receive the props and render to the virtual DOM. What I see, however, is that they are full-blown stateful monsters and I have found no way to treat them like functions.

**The question:** Why is each usage of a React component wrapped in `React.createElement`? Why can't I use `new MyComponent()` instead? It looks pretty similar when I do it in DevTools. Why is `React.createElement` needed at all, given that components are created using `React.createClass`? It looks like redundant to me.

Edit: this looks relevant: https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/ae327f2eda03bf165261

Edit #2: This is related, but not a duplicate of [React.Component vs React.createClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668464), that question asks about creating classes. I'm not asking about creating new component classes, I'm asking about creating instances (elements) of that classes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [React.Component vs React.createClass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668464/react-component-vs-react-createclass)

Answer (score 1):

I think I [found the answer here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sebmarkbage/d7bce729f38730399d28/raw/81e0e24c2e7453e9e5744777fb0b3dbfeb9e4280/ElementFactoriesAndJSX.md):

> In React 0.12, we're making a core change to how React.createClass(...) and JSX works.
>
> (...)
>
> Currently `var Button = React.createClass(...)` does two things. It
>   creates a class and a helper function to create ReactElements. It is
>   essentially equivalent to this:
>
> ````
> class ButtonClass { }
>
> function ButtonFactory(...args) {   return
> React.createElement(ButtonClass, ...args); }
>
> module.exports = ButtonFactory; ```
> ````
>
> Then you access this in the consuming component by invoking the
>   ButtonFactory.
>
> ```
> var Button = require('Button');
>
> class App {   render() {
>     return Button({ prop: 'foo '}); // ReactElement
> } }
> ```
>
> Conceptually this is the wrong model. The source component should not
>   be responsible for the output of App.
>
> There are a few problems with this:
>
> - ES6 classes can't be directly exported, they need to be wrapped.
> - There's no convenient way to access the actual class and it's confusing which one you're using.
> - Static methods are wrapped in helpers that are not real function. As a convenience.
> - Auto-mocking destroys the factory so there is no way to test the result of render without disabling mocking.
> - Factories can be wrapped by other factories that returns something different than ReactElements. Making testing and optimizations
>     impossible.
> - Languages with specialized features for object management have to defer to React instead of using the built-in features.