# When creating React components should I use functional components, React.createClass or extends React.Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am quite new to React and have been reading up a lot about it. I have come across three different methods to create components:

**Functional Components:**

```
const Hello = ({world}) => {
  return (
    <div>{"Hello" + world}</div>
  );     
}
```

**React.createClass (Factory):**

```
const Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>{"Hello" + this.props.world}</div>
  }
});
```

**ES6 Class Extends**

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{"Hello" + this.props.world}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Apart from the obvious that the functional components don't have any state coupled to it and is probably a more functional approach to doing components, why would I use the different methods?

In the React documentation they use all three methods.  Some of the [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668464/react-component-vs-react-createclass) articles suggest the Class method and then some suggest the Factory method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using functional is recommended for components that are stateless.

Using `React.Component` extend is recommended if you are working with ES6+/TypeScript code. React Native has support only for this type of component creation.

`React.createClass` is for used with ES5.

Browsers will soon have a complete support and Facebook recommends to use [React.Component instead of React.createClass](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/10/react-v0.13.html) and to use [functional for stateless](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html#components-can-be-classes-or-functions).

**Edit**

Facebook added a [deprecation warning to React.createClass in React 15.6.0](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/06/13/react-v15.6.0.html) and points users to use [`create-react-class`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-class) instead.

Comment: But Facebook also recommends using [functional](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html#components-can-be-classes-or-functions)

Comment: They recommend using _functional stateless_ components for those components in which you do not need to keep state and don't need the lifecycle methods (onComponentDidMount, shouldComponentUpdate, etc)

Comment: I guess this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions) explains it.
Use functional components as far as possible (there will be performance optimizations in the future).  This is recommended.
When local state or lifecycle hooks are necessary in the component use ES6 class syntax.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, it is recommend to use functional component when you need just create **presentational logic component**. For component that has any logic we use smth like **React.createClass()**.

There are two ways of doing that:

*First*, you create general component and than divide it on presentational logic and business logic.

*Second*, you can create them alongside.

**Be careful! When divide these components, your business logic must render your presentational logic!**

For more practice see tutorials on the *codecademy*