# Which grammar is better for Component of React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question when learning React.js.

According to the official documents or some textbooks, I found there are two ways of express react code. But I couldn't get which way is better.

```
class SampleComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: 'react'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <p> Hello {this.state.value} !! </p>
    );
  }
}
```

and the other is this.

```
var SampleComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      value: 'react'
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <p> Hello {this.state.value} !! </p>
    );
  }
});
```

Can someone explain which is what, and which way is better?
Thanks.

Comment: There is no "better" way per se. One is ES6 syntax and the other ES5 syntax. They are completely equivalent but ES6 needs a special transpiler - so it depends on what version you're using. The former (ES6) is liked as its new and offers classes and methods but has its downsides such as no autobinding of this.

Comment: You can look at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668464/react-component-vs-react-createclass

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know ES5 and ES6. The given url also answers my question clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Both are fine. The first one is [ES2015](https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#ecmascript-2015-features-classes) (or ES6) code, it's not supported by some older browsers, so usually people use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to compile the code to ES5 code (the second one).

But for developers, the ES2015 syntax is much clearer and easier to write, also because the JSX still needs to be compiled, you use babel anyway. You can just go for ES2015, but I'd recommend you to have a solid ES5 skill before learning ES2015.

Answer (score 0):

I wont reiterate the difference between versions, but the second example offers better readability- very intuitive.  If you are still learning React or working with others who may still be learning, ES5 makes everybody happy.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I didn't know ES5, ES6 and their differences.
I'm interested in using ES6, but I'm new to js and so as many coders. so I will use ES5 instead of ES6.

Comment: You should use comment if you want to reply an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Class notation is Es6 format and it has lots of benefit.

1. It's more readable at least for OOPS programmer (Java, C++).
2. Binding of "this" context is more easier and clear (using arrow function).
3. Pollute less global scope if you are using let and const keyword.
4. Easy to emulate the prototype inheritance (In this case extending React.Component)
5. Most importantly, it uses Es6 module to organise code.

   ```
   class SampleComponent extends React.Component {
             constructor() {
               super();
               this.state = {
                 value: 'react'
               };
             }

             render() {
               return (
                 <p> Hello {this.state.value} !! </p>
               );
             }
           }
   ```